# Retrieve all the classes annotated with a specific annotation(s)

Tags: scala

I have defined a simple annotation in scala like this

```
case class MyAnnotation(value: String) extends StaticAnnotation
```

and then some classes that use this annotation

```
@MyAnnotation("en_US")
class TestAnnotation
```

Now, I would like to get at runtime **all** the classes annotated with such annotation, but the documentation about [mirrors](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html) and [annotations](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/annotations-names-scopes) in scala-reflect is not clear at all :-/

Can anybody shed some lights on how to perform such runtime search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214579/scala-reflection-finding-and-instantiating-all-classes-with-a-given-annotation) most likely the same question was asked and it was recommended to use [reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). [Here](http://www.47deg.com/blog/scala-macros-annotate-your-case-classes) there is a sample of processing annotation with macro.

Hope these links will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks but I already saw that answer, and it's wrong. For the simple fact that [" ... Moreover, **subclassing scala.annotation.ClassfileAnnotation does not make your annotation visible as a Java annotation at runtime; that requires writing the annotation class in Java."](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/annotations-names-scopes). Which in turn makes the reflections library useless.  Same goes for the last link, since  it' being done at compile time, not at runtime as I asked.
In short: runtime annotations are broken (hence why they are still experimental)

Comment: Yeah, but you could fallback to java annotations if you need this kind of functionality.

Comment: Indeed, but since I'm starting a project from scratch in Scala, I just wanted to stick to the language as much as possible. And, since it's been around for 12 years, it's kind of depressing to notice how this problem isn't solved yet...